# Playing audio with video using MediaDecoder

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediacodec

I have an MPEG2-transport file, and using the newfangled MediaCodec API in Android, I can play the video frames. I'm using MediaExtractor to load the file, and call getTrackFormat to get a MediaFormat. The reported MIME type for the format is "video/avc".

Is there a straightforward way to play the audio at the same time, and make sure the video and audio are synchronized?

I'm aware of the SimplePlayer sample code for stagefright, but that's in C and uses undocumented interfaces. Can it be done in Java?

Comment: What audio type do you have in this file? How many tracks getTrackCount () returns?

Comment: It's straightforward until you get to the "audio and video are synchronized" part. It got a bit easier in 4.4 "KitKat" with the `eglPresentationTimeANDROID` extension, but you still need to know the audio pipeline latency.

Comment: Yes, I found the separate audio track, and I'm able to play it just fine. The MIME type is audio/mp4a-latm. What is the best way to synchronize the audio and video? My first thought is to spin up separate Java threads for the audio and video. Since the audio seems to play at the correct speed, use the audio played so far to cue the video.

Comment: I wrote a loop that plays the audio, and then plays as much video as needed to catch up to the audio. That works well so far, though I may need to account for latencies, as mentioned above.

Comment: I found the page containing documentation for eglPresentationTimeANDROID: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGLExt.html. But there's no description of what it does!

Comment: Although my app runs fine on a Nexus 7 (2013), it fails in an emulator. I created a Nexus 10 emulator with GPU emulation. The app fails in a few seconds with a segfault in libc, preceded by: OMXNodeInstance(904): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed.