# Android - How to play audio along with video using Media libraries in Android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have been trying for a couple of days now to play an mp4 file that I recorded using the Android MediaRecorder sample. http://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRecorder/index.html

I am using this sample over here MediaDecoder to play the video. This is able to play the video but I cannot seem to play the sound at all. http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicMediaDecoder/index.html

Do I need to create another MediaExtractor to decode the audio track from the above piece? Should I be using an AudioTrack? for this. The mime type of the audio is an AAC {audio/mp4a-latm}

A similar question was asked here but there was no answer.
[Playing audio with video using MediaDecoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445794/playing-audio-with-video-using-mediadecoder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), it's provided by Google to give some right samples working around Video/Audio decode&encode issue, and also [here](http://www.bigflake.com/mediacodec/) is a good place to refer.

Comment: Hi jobraczy, I have the grafika with me, but it does not have any articles about playing an audio with it. I was able to play the mp4 video I had but the audio is not there. Any ideas which example I need to look at?

Comment: See here https://code.google.com/p/android-openmxplayer/ , it's a good sample of audio play with MediaCodec & AudioTracker